# Auto Delete when Page Reloads

Tags: php, laravel

How do i automatically reloads the page when is clicked on the navigation bar? I have this line of code.  This code deletes a notification when the blood campaign already exceeded the campaign end date.

I have a table like this.

```
Latest Blood Campaign
---------------------------------------------------
id      CampaignTitle  CampaignAddress CampaignStartDate CampaignEndDate
1       Blood Letting   New York         2016-02-24      2016-02-26




Admin Send Notifications
------------------------------------------------------------
id       receiver        messageBody
1          jk             Please come to our blood campaign



My code to delete notification.


          <?php 
          $dateToday2 = '2016-02-29';

          $latest2 = LatestBloodCampaign::all();                        
          foreach ( $latest2 as $data2 )

          if($dateToday2 <= $data2->campaignEndDate)
          { }else{ 

          DB::table('admin_send_notifications')
                          ->where('receiver', 'jk')
                          ->where('messageBody', $notification->messageBody)
                          ->delete();
          } ?>
```

I put this line of code into the notification page so when it loads it automatically deletes but when it is only click on the navigation bar it does not delete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a route dedicated to deleting `Campaigns`. A link to the route will trigger the route and the response should be a redirect back to the route that served the initial page.